# python script to send commands to vim (mvim)

Tags: python, vim, macvim

I wrote a very simple vim plugin and python script trying to test some communication between the two. My vim-script looks like this:

```
function! HelloWorld()
    silent :!python helloworld.py
endf

nmap <C-P> :call HelloWorld()<CR>
```

then my python script looks like this:

```
import os;

os.system( 'mvim --servername VIM -u NONE -U NONE --remote-send \"<C-\\\\><C-N>:echo \'Hello World!\'<CR>\"' )
```

If I am in vim and press , use the ":call HelloWorld()" command, or just type ":!python helloworld.py" from the same or another mvim or vim instance, nothing happens. However, if I call the script from the command line separately, mvim responds appropriately: shows "Hello World!" along the bottom.

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working when called from vim?

Comment: Curious why you are calling it as mvim rather than gvim?

Comment: I think mvim is a shortened form of macvim http://code.google.com/p/macvim/

Comment: Are you aware that you can recompile Vim so it interfaces to Python internally?  There is no need for inflexible kludge of running Python at command line; interfacing with built-in support is easier, faster, more flexible and powerful, requires only recompiling Vim.  See help at `:h python`.

Comment: @Herbert I am mildly aware of the python compile option. If I am planning to release my plugin to the public, does it really make sense to be dependent on vim being compiled with the python option? I use the Command-T plugin for example which is awesome, but I really wish I didn't have to build vim myself to use it. I guess I would prefer most plugins to work out of the box unless there is a really big performance benefit of custom builds, but am I underestimating users' willingness to do custom builds considering vim's user base is going to be pretty technical anyway?

Comment: You're right, that's a valid reason for not wanting to use  built-in python support.  If distribution is the plan, though, seems like it would be better to just build it in VimScript, since even your external calls to python will have problems on some systems (I'm thinking especially of Windows here).  Maybe it depends on whether what you want is already done in python or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
silent :!python helloworld.py
```

with

```
silent :!(sleep 0.5s && python helloworld.py) &
redraw!
```

(the point is in returning to vim before remote command arrives). If it works, then the problem is in processing remote commands while receiving shell output. You can also try another workarounds:

```
call system('python helloworld.py')
```

,

```
call system('python helloworld.py &')
```

and

```
pyfile helloworld.py
```

(Note that the last one requires vim compiled with +python feature and also alters the state of python interpreter used by vim).

By the way, use `system()` call instead of `!` when you don't want to see the script output. Also use `redraw!` after `silent !`.

Comment: It turned out to be a stupid typo...mistyped the script name. However, I still tried to change it to use "system()" instead. Vim tells me that system is not a command if I start out the line that way. Can you give me an example of how the line should look (with redraw and everything)? I am not completely understanding what you are suggesting

Comment: @drewag I forgot `call` in front of `system()`. Updated. Line with redraw is simple: just put `redraw!` on the next line after `silent !...`.